# Cron to delete particular file(s) from a specific directory

Tags: shell, files, cron

I am trying to write a cron  for unix shell that will delete some files, say after 2 weeks or after 1 month from a specific directory.

/somedir1/somedir2/

```
if(somedir2) contains file with extension .txt or .log 
then
check timestamp
if two weeks old delete it
otherwise don't delete.
```

Comment: The `find` command does everything you need.  `man find`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `find` command.

```
find /somedir1/somedir2 -name *.txt -name *.log -mtime 2w -delete
```

Change `-delete` to `-print` for a dry run.

Answer (score 2):

You could also leverage `tmpwatch` http://linux.die.net/man/8/tmpwatch, using whichever parameters of `atime`, `ctime`, or `mtime` suit your needs.

For example, `tmpwatch --atime 30d /foo` will remove all files in /foo that haven't been accessed in 30 days.